# Time complexity when Stream, string split and collect are used together

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have to split a string using comma delimiters and lookup a value in it. I am thinking which way is faster splitting string in array and checking if array contains it or splitting string in Set and doing lookup in Set.

I want to know what is the time complexity of below two statements in Java:

```java
// statement #1
Set<String> result = Stream.of(givenString.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toSet());

// statement #2
String[] split = givenString.trim().split(",");
```

Are they both `O(n)` ?

Comment: Since you are asking about internal time complexity of some data structure operations in a programming language or library, you should mention what that language or library is.

Comment: Added 'java' language

Comment: Why don't you use [String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `n` be the string length, `k` the number of comma-separated words, and `w` the maximum length of a word. Also, lets assume that our unit cost is character comparison/copying.

Splitting the string to words (`String.split()` method) will cost `O(n)`.

Building a `Set` from these words will cost `O(k * log(k) * w)` if `Set` is implemented as `TreeSet`, or `O(k * w)` if `Set` is implemented as `HashSet` (with some sensible load factor). So, roughly `O(n * log(n))` and `O(n)` respectively. Searching in a `Set` will be `O(log(k) * w)` and `O(1)` respectively (roughly `O(log(n))` and `O(1)`).

Building an array (or `ArrayList`) will cost `O(k * w)` or roughly `O(n)`.
Searching in an array will be also `O(k * w)`.

So, if you are going to perform only a few searches, it doesn't make much sense to build a `Set`; you can use simple (sequential) search in an `List` (e.g with `List.indexOf`). But if you are going to perform many searches, building a `Set` in advance, will certainly be more effective.